# Counting rows based on individual columns, and the sum of multiple columns

Tags: excel

In excel, I need to count the number of rows based on criteria from values in individual columns, and from the sum of a set of multiple columns.

For example, with the attached image of data, I want to be able to count the number of rows which are "valid" (= when Column A = 1), are over 17 years old (= Column B = >17), and when the sum of columns C to G are equal to zero.

I am currently using `countifs` function, with individual criteria for columns C to G being zero. However, with my actual data there are many more columns than C to G so the formula becomes too large, they are taking a long time to write and very vulnerable to mistakes.

I have tried using `sumproduct` but this has the same problem with a long formula.

Formulas I have tried;

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A, 1, $B:$B, ">17", $C:$C, 0, $D:$D,0, $E:$E,0,  $F:$F,0, $G:$G,0)

=SUMPRODUCT(($A:$A=1)*($B:$B>17)*($C:$C=0)*($D:$D=0)*($E:$E=0)*($F:$F=0)*($G:$G=0))
```

I know I could create a new column with an `If` function for the sum of columns C-G first `(=IF(SUM(C2:G2)=0, 1, 0))`, and then include this as a criteria (new column = 1) within a `countifs`, but I would like to avoid creating new columns with this data.

I would like to do `=COUNTIFS($A:$A, 1, $B:$B, ">17", C:G, SUM(C:G)=0)`, but sum within `countifs` is not possible.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated?

**Image of data:**

[image: Data]

**Sample data:**

```
| Valid | Age | a | b | c | d | e |
|-------|-----|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1     | 18  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0     | 8   | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0     | 48  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1     | 22  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

Comment: I'd like to help but I'm not sure I understand. *`with my actual data there are many more columns than C to G so the formula becomes too large`*.  How many more columns, and do they each have different criteria?  If it's just making sure they are all zero, that's pretty easy.

Comment: so what you're trying to do is have a single column indicating whether the record is Valid, and Valid mean (column B > 17) and (columns C to __ = 0 ) correct?  How many columns in reality?

Comment: I am not trying to indicate whether it is valid or not, the valid 1's and 0's are already set. I am trying to have a cell which counts the number of rows when column A = 1, column B = >18 and the sum of column C to G = zero. There are up to 30 columns in total for the criteria of sum of equalling zero.

Comment: No problem, its still doable with a worksheet function. Which cells are being counted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you're unhappy with your `COUNTIFS` formula, but here's an efficient way to still use `COUNTIFS` (shorter/easier than VBA) **and maintain accuracy**.

> The formula with your example would be: 
>   **`=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,">=18",C:C,,D:D,,E:E,,F:F,,G:G,)`**
>
> This is likely *similar* what you were using, but note:
>
> - If the criteria is `"=0"` then no criteria need to be specified between the commas.
> - If the function applies to the entire column, there is no need to specify row numbers.
>     <sub>In fact, even if there's other values
>     above/below your data (like headings), they'll be ignored
>
>     (unless they
>     meet all the criteria in the formula, which would be unlikely.)</sub>

---

### Want to avoid errors? *Make Excel write the formula for you!*

If you're concerned about making errors when adjusting the formula to your actual data, let Excel do the work for you with three steps.  (First **save** your workbook.)

1. **Select each column** (or a cell from each column) that you want to include in your formula.  <sub>(To select multiple areas, click the first one and then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you click the rest.)</sub>
2. **Copy the line below** by highlighting it and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

   ```
   ?"=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,"">=18""";:For Each c In Selection.Columns:?","&Columns(c.Column).Address&",";:Next c:?")"
   ```
3. **Hit** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>  <sub>(This immediately runs the VBA code from Step 2.)</sub>

**The formula will appear on the next line**. Just copy/paste into to where you want it!

<sub>Example output:</sub>
`=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,">=18",$C:$C,,$F:$F,,$G:$G,,$P:$P,,$T:$T,,$AJ:$AJ,,$AC:$AC,)`

---

### Edit:

I'm not sure why you want/need to use `INDIRECT` but it's fine as long as you maintain the same syntax.  A simplified example:

I have values in Columns A and B.  I want to count rows where A=1 and B=1.  My `COUNTIFS` formula (in `D2`) would be:  `=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,1)`

[image: img]

The reason to use `INDIRECT` could be if, for example, I don't always want this to use Column B -- I want to be able to specify which column to use, in a different cell, maybe `D5`.

In `D5` I enter the text: `B:B`.  Then I change the formula is `D2`, replacing `B:B` with `INDIRECT(D5)`.

[image: img]

Since `E2` contains the text `B:B`, the formula is still *indirectly* referring to `B:B`, and the result of the formula does not change.  If I specify a different column range in `E2`, the formula will look at the new range.

> **Important Note:**
>
> With `SUMIFS`, `COUNTIFS` and `AVERAGEIFS`, *all* ranges specified **must have the same number of rows and columns** as the *`criteria_range1`* argument.
>
> In this formula, that means they must be **entire columns**.

If you're just trying to refer to a column on a different worksheet, that's fine as long as you use correct syntax, such as: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,Sheet1!D:D,1)` to refer to column D on `Sheet1`.

If the name of the sheet is contained as text in a cell (`D5`), but you want the column (`D:D`) still hard-coded, then your `INDIRECT` section of the formula would be: `INDIRECT(D5&"!D:D")`

[image: img]

**If the specified worksheet name has a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in it,** then you need to surround the name with `'` apostophes, in the correct spot:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,INDIRECT("'" & D5&"'!D:D"),1)
```

...which is one of the many reasons spaces and other *non-alphanumeric characters* should be avoided when naming "anything".

Comment: Thank you, really helpful.. Using commas for zeros will save me some time. Having excel write the formula could also be really useful. I have attempted this, but I cannot get it to work. The exact formula format I am trying to use it on is;  " =COUNTIFS('Sample 1 checks'!$B:$B,1, INDIRECT("'"&'Cover page'!$C$10&"'!$IG:$IG"),1,INDIRECT("'"&'Cover page'!$C$10&"'!$AR:$AR"), , INDIRECT("'"&'Cover page'!$C$10&"'!$AS:$AS"), , [then repeated from columns AR to BV equalling zero]". Does having INDIRECT functions in here make it not possible to automatically copy?

Comment: let me know if you need any explanation on the modified answer

Comment: Thanks. Sorry first time posting and thought it would help to simplify it. Your answer has helped so I have liked it.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with a `custom function` using VBA. A `custom function` is a self programmed function that can be used as a normal function in an Excel cell. the function is called `countCorrectEntries` and takes a Range as Parameter. So if your table(including header) is located in `A1:G5` the function in your target cell would be `=countCorrectEntries(A1:G5)` What it essentialy does is, it initiallizes a variable `countCorrect=0` which is going to count all rows that fullfill all conditions.
The loop:

```
For i = 2 To UBound(table, 1)
...
Next i
```

Goes through the rows and checks the conditions that look as follows:

```
    If table(i, columnNumber) <> condition Then
        conditionsMet = False
    End If
```

It checks in row i (the iterator) if in a column e.g 1 for first does not meet a certain condition. E.g value is not equal to 1. If that is so, a boolean conditionsMet is set to `False` and it is not counted as correct.

For your sum problem, I propose the following condition:

```
    'Check sum
    tempSum = 0
    For j = startColumn To EndColumn
        tempSum = tempSum + table(i, j)
    Next j

    If tempSum > 0 Then
        conditionsMet = False
    End If
```

The loop within the loop goes over the columns between `startColumn` and `endColumn` e.g `3 and 7 for column C to G` and sums the values in tempSum. Then it is checked if the sum is greater 0 and again the `conditionsMet is set to False` if so.

If after all the conditions are checked the `conditionsMet is still True` then `CountCorrect is incremented by 1`.

The following code should work for your problem. Just change the inner loop values for the correct columns and you are all set.

Cheers!

```
Function countCorrectEntries(Rng As Range)

Dim table As Variant
table = Rng

countCorrect = 0
For i = 2 To UBound(table, 1)
    conditionsMet = True

    If table(i, 1) <> 1 Then
        conditionsMet = False
    End If
    If table(i, 2) < 18 Then
        conditionsMet = False
    End If

    'Check sum
    tempSum = 0
    For j = 3 To 7
        tempSum = tempSum + table(i, j)
    Next j

    If tempSum > 0 Then
        conditionsMet = False
    End If

    If conditionsMet = True Then
        countCorrect = countCorrect + 1
    End If
Next i

countCorrectEntries = countCorrect

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. It was really useful to learn how to do this. With my data though, I am using the same formula countifs format repeatedly and changing the criteria and column references. I would therefore need to be creating many different versions of these which reference the different columns, which I am not sure is possible? And feel would still take some time if had to do individual ones.